# When using a nav and tab bar controller, why does didMove only fire once?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller, uitabbar

This is the setup I'm trying to work with:

[image]

As you can see, the structure goes like this:

*Navigation Controller > View Controller > Tab Bar Controller > View Controller*

I'm trying to pass data through the back button and typically, all I have to do is fire `didMove` from the view controller *with* the back button like this:

```
override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    if (!(parent?.isEqual(self.parent) ?? false)) {
        print("Parent view loaded")
    }
}
```

However, when I place this inside `TabItem01ViewController.swift` or `TabItem02ViewController.swift`, nothing seems to be fired. If I place the code in `TabViewController.swift`, however, `didMove` is fired. I can't seem to figure out why it's getting fired from `TabViewController.swift` but not either of the tabs views.

---

**So my question is**: how do I pass data from either of the tabs to the `ViewController.swift` file when the back button is pressed?